# What is the best way to deal with the mandatory left margin that comes with grid-column in Bourbon Neat 2.0 above?

Tags: css, css-grid, bourbon, neat

This is the output of a grid-column mixin as mentioned on the site -

.element {

```
  width: calc(25% - 25px);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
```

}

My **problem** is that I don't want gutters before and after the first and last columns.

Bootstrap uses a row class that has negative left and right margins to adjust the column padding.Is a similar approach suggested for Neat layout?

Comment: What is the problem you want to deal with?

Comment: Why would this question be downvoted without explanation?

Comment: It is not clear if you have a problem you want to solve...

Comment: Hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@grid-collpase](https://neat.bourbon.io/docs/2.0.0/#grid-collapse) to consume the gutters of a container.

Output:

```
.element {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

Here is a pen example https://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/RjOEyb

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Even if I use a custom grid, won't it add a margin anyway since I am going to still use the grid-column mixin ?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your updated question :)

Comment: I'll give it to you